# Linq to SQL Cast Exception

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm starting my first Linq to SQL project in VB.NET (which I am also new to). 
I am trying to Delete an entity but am having trouble with an InvalidCastException. The debugger breaks at the Next statement in the ForEach loop.

My entity class is called Material.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Kenneth

```
        Dim materialsTable As Table(Of Material) _
                 = (New DataContext("Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=Materials; Trusted_Connection=yes;") _
                    .GetTable(Of Material)())

        Dim materialsToDelete = (From x In materialsTable _
                                 Where x.MaterialName = aMaterial.MaterialName _
                                 Select x)

        If (materialsToDelete Is Nothing) Then Return
        If (materialsToDelete.Count = 0) Then Return

        For Each m As Material In materialsToDelete
            materialsTable.DeleteOnSubmit(m)
        Next

        materialsTable.Context.SubmitChanges()
```

Comment: I don't see any problems with your code.  Is there anything you left out for the sake of brevity?  Are there any other objects associated with Material?

Comment: No, Material is a very basic class with just a few properties.

Comment: can you add the exact exception message + stack trace?

Comment: Here's the exception details:

A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
   at Read_Material(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
   at MaterialEditor.Data.MaterialRepository.DeleteMaterial(Material aMaterial) in \MaterialRepository.vb:line 44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you actually run the query with a .ToList()

Also, go with a straightforward DataContext if you can. I've not seen your implementation of the DC anywhere.

```
 Dim db as new NorthwindDataContext()
 Dim materialsToDelete = (From x In db.Materials _
                             Where x.MaterialName = aMaterial.MaterialName _
                             Select x)
```

You actually don't need to loop to delete them.

```
materialsTable.DeleteAllOnSubmit(materialsToDelete)
materialsTable.Context.SubmitChanges()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Using .ToList() results in an InvalidCastException on that line..

Comment: @KennethC: how about explicitly declaring the type of materialsToDelete?  Also, go with a new DataContext object, rather than your current approach.

Comment: Ended up reverting back the the VS designer and the generated context works fine.